# 'Package install failed' in angular js

Tags: angularjs, installation-package

I had this error during creating the app in visual studio as well as the 
command prompt. It's my first time with angular js I don't know how to 
deal with this error. Can anyone help me, please! I'm using npm version 10.6

```
> D:\My_Stuff\Codes\Angular_js>ng new baseapp
CREATE baseapp/angular.json (3557 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/package.json (1311 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/README.md (1024 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/tsconfig.json (384 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/tslint.json (2805 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/environments/environment.ts (631 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/index.html (294 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/main.ts (370 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/polyfills.ts (3194 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/browserslist (375 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/tsconfig.app.json (194 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/tsconfig.spec.json (282 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (990 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/app/app.component.ts (207 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (303 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
CREATE baseapp/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-25T18_58_01_108Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Comment: did u see the details in `2018-07-25T18_58_01_108Z-debug.log`

Comment: Can you update the post adding the current npm version that you're using? Thanks.

Comment: @carmelolg I'm using npm version10.6

Comment: npm version 10.6 ? that's not a npm version

Comment: sorry my mistake, its npm v6.1.0 and node v10.6.0

Comment: Did you upgrade node and npm version recently?

Comment: yes, I did... 1st I had node v6.11 and now v10.6

Answer (score 0):

if show this error then hit this command

`npm cache clean --force`

if you had  hit this command previously then problem in your npm (nodejs)

> Try To reinstall npm(nodejs)